# Fluentd custom parser plugin raises uninitialized constant Fluent error

Tags: ruby, parsing, plugins, fluentd

I am trying to implement a custom [fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/) parser plugin. As suggested in the [docs](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/plugin-development#parser-plugins), I have created the following file called `parser_unordered_multiline.rb` and put it in the location `/etc/td-agent/plugin/`.

```
# @Package:     Fluentd
# @Module:      Unordered Multiline Parser Plugin
# @Author:      Amyth Singh <mail@amythsingh.com>
#
#    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
#    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
#    You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#    limitations under the License.


module Fluent
    class TextParser
        class UnorderedMultilineParser < Parser

            Plugin.register_parser('unordered_multiline', self)

            ## Define configuration params
            config_param :delimiter, :string, :default => " "
            config_param :time_format, :string, :default => nil

            ## configures our parser plugin
            def configure(conf)
                super

                if @delimiter.length != 1
                    raise ConfigError, "delimiter must be a single character. #{@delimiter} is not."
                end

                @time_parser = TimeParser.new(@time_format)
            end


            def parse(text)
                time, key_values = text.split(" ", 2)
                time = @time_parser.parse(time)
                record = {}
                key_values.split(@delimiter).each { |kv|
                    k, v = kv.split("=", 2)
                    record[k] = v
                }

                yield time, record

            end
        end
    end
end
```

I am using the same code given in the [example in the documentation](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/plugin-development#parser-plugins) (just with a different name) but the fluentd logs show the error:

```
unexpected error error="uninitialized constant Fluent::TextParser::Parser"
```

Following is the full stack trace

```
2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [info]: starting fluentd-0.10.50
2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [info]: reading config file path="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf"
2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: unexpected error error="uninitialized constant Fluent::TextParser::Parser"
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /etc/td-agent/plugin/parser_unordered_multiline.rb:21:in `<class:TextParser>'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /etc/td-agent/plugin/parser_unordered_multiline.rb:20:in `<module:Fluent>'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /etc/td-agent/plugin/parser_unordered_multiline.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.10.50/lib/fluent/plugin.rb:59:in `block in load_plugin_dir'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.10.50/lib/fluent/plugin.rb:57:in `each'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.10.50/lib/fluent/plugin.rb:57:in `load_plugin_dir'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.10.50/lib/fluent/engine.rb:129:in `load_plugin_dir'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.10.50/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:369:in `block in init_engine'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.10.50/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:366:in `each'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.10.50/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:366:in `init_engine'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.10.50/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:129:in `block in start'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.10.50/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:246:in `call'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.10.50/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:246:in `main_process'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.10.50/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:221:in `block in supervise'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.10.50/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:220:in `fork'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.10.50/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:220:in `supervise'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.10.50/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:126:in `start'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.10.50/lib/fluent/command/fluentd.rb:160:in `<top (required)>'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:73:in `require'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.10.50/bin/fluentd:6:in `<top (required)>'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/fluentd:23:in `load'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/bin/fluentd:23:in `<top (required)>'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /usr/sbin/td-agent:7:in `load'
  2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [error]: /usr/sbin/td-agent:7:in `<main>'
2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [info]: process finished code=256
2015-12-23 14:38:23 +0530 [warn]: process died within 1 second. exit.
```

And this is how my configuration file looks like.

```
<source>
    type tail
    path /var/log/mail/mail*
    pos_file /var/log/td-agent/tmp/access.log
    exclude_path ["/var/log/mail/*.gz", "/var/log/mail/*.zip"]
    read_from_head true
    time_format %M %d %H:%M:%S
    port 5140
    format unordered_multiline
    tag  mail
</source>


<match mail>
    type copy
    <store>
       type elasticsearch
       logstash_format true
       flush_interval 30s
    </store>
</match>
```

I am fairly new to ruby and fluentd, Can anybody tell me what this error is all about ?

### update

According to the [plugin management docs](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/plugin-management), even the path seems correct